# how to exclude certain files from compiling

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I am extending my android application flavour as follow

```
wetProd {
            java.srcDirs = sourceSets.ukProd.java.srcDirs
        }
```

There is one class called model in helloProd flavour that I want to exclude during the compile time. I am find it difficult that how to use

`exclude 'mytasks/model.java'`

in the above gradle command.

Many thanks.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is how we can do this in our **build.gradle** of app module.

sample

```
packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude '.README'
        }
```

follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955887/exclude-files-using-proguard-rules) one for more details

Comment: you did not get my question.

Answer (score 0):

> source set is what specifies what source is to be compiled

```
sourceSets {
main {
    java {
        srcDir 'src'
        exclude '**/uncompilable/**'
   }
```

}
}

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I cannot figure out how to add exclude in my code that I wrote in my question. I am using that code in sourcesets.